# CLI in C++: cin and Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, windows, command-line-interface

I have an infinite loop to implement a custom CLI, as follows

```
while (1) {
    getline(cin, _input);
    _parse_cmd(_input);
}
```

I created a signal handler as follows:

```
BOOL WINAPI _consoleSignalHandler(DWORD CEvent) {
    char mesg[128];

    switch (CEvent)
    {
    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        if (_CLI_instance) {
            cout << "Close Signal" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        cout << "Ctrl + C to be implemented" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

With this configuration, when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the CLI prints the message `"Ctrl + C to be implemented"`and never waits for user input again. How can I solve this?

NOTE: `parse_cmd` is a generic command parser that executes simple actions

Comment: What is _parse_cmd ?

Comment: @MarcoA. it's a simple function for command parsing, executes simple actions only

Comment: Why not disable `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` mode, so CTRL+C is reported as keyboard input rather than as a signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit :

Your problem is that in C++, when the `getline` function is interrupted, you have to manually clear the error state before next call. It is enough in your loop to write :

```
while (1) {

    getline(cin, _input);
     if (cin.fail() || cin.eof()) {
        cin.clear(); // reset cin state
    }
   _parse_cmd(_input);

}
```

But beware: as you also filter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd>, you loop could be hard to stop ...

TL/DR : Below are my first steps to this simple solution first in C idiom, next in C++ one, that only filter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and are killed on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd>.

You can obtain easily the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> interception with the `signal` function.

Here is an example of usage :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void ctrl_c(int sig) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Ctrl-C caught\n");
    signal(sig, ctrl_c); /* re-installs handler */
}

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    void (*old)(int);

    old = signal(SIGINT, ctrl_c); /* installs handler */

    for (;;) {
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
            printf("Got : %s", buf);
        }
    }
    signal(SIGINT, old); /* restore initial handler */
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is intercepted, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> kills the program.

Edit :

Old C version was straightforward. In C++ you have to clear flags in `cin` if `getline` was interrupted :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <csignal>

using namespace std;

void ctrl_c(int sig) {
    cerr << "Ctrl-C caught" << endl;
    signal(sig, ctrl_c); // re-installs handler
}

int main() {
    string buf;
    void (*old)(int);

    old = signal(SIGINT, ctrl_c); // installs handler

    for (;;) {
        getline(cin, buf);
        if (cin.fail() || cin.eof()) {
            cin.clear(); // reset cin state
        }
        else {
            cout << "Got" << buf << endl;
        }
    }
    signal(SIGINT, old); // restore initial handler
    return 0;
}
```

It's now correct C++ even if I do not use the Microsoft specific `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. IMHO signal usage if more simple if only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> has to be caught.

Comment: Why did you change the OP's code from C++ into 1920s C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because I had this old code that I once used (long, long time ago ...) and I was sure it worked. But you are right, it did not answer OP question :-( . Thanks for the comment.